# Transition not working on Position attributes like Top, Left, etc

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the first `li` element to "transition to the top left side of the viewport, almost as to pin it, when the page loads.  Whenever I load my page though, it's already in that position rather than transitioning from where it was to where the `drift` class has it.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            Header Name
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    item 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    item 2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
 ul li {
            display: flex;
            text-decoration: none;
            flex-direction: row;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
      }
       .drift {
            transition: all 9s linear;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
       }
```

**JS**

```
    let li = document.querySelector('li');

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        li.className += "drift";
    })
```

Comment: Try to create your var inside you event and put a space before `drift`

Comment: Change it to `li.classList.add("drift")` and add `transition-delay: 300ms;` to the drift css.

Comment: @JulienBourdic it's the only class on that element so the spacing shouldn't matter, i don' think

Comment: @ptothep just tried but same result

Comment: `top` and `left` are different properties than `bottom` and `right`. Since `top` and `left` basically override the `bottom` and `right` properties, and since they were previously undefined, their new value is applied instantly as there was no previous valid value to transition from. I guess I'll try explaining it better in an answer.

Comment: @OskarGrosser that makes sense.  How can I be 'transitioning' if those are new properties in that class, right?  How could I accomplish that then?

Comment: You could set the initial/final `left`/`right` and `top`/`bottom` values using JavaScript and `Element.clientWidth`/`Element.clientHeight`. Or you could make use of the CSS-property `transform`. As I said, I'll explain it better in my upcoming answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to trigger the function after a delay.

See the snippet below:

```js
let li = document.querySelector('li');


window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setTimeout(myFunc, 1000)
});

function myFunc() {
  li.className += "drift";
}
```

```css
ul li {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.drift {
  transition: all 9s linear slideInFromLeft;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      Header Name
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          item 1
        </li>
        <li>
          item 2
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

`top` and `left` have a higher priority over `bottom` and `right`. This means, when these are declared, they override the effect of the "less important" properties.
See it here:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>I am placed both left and right,<br>but left takes priority!</div>
```

Since `top` and `bottom` are different CSS-properties, meaning transitioning between them is impossible.
Another reason is, `top` takes priority, we are essentially trying to transition from "undefined" to a newly declared value. Since this is impossible, CSS immediately applies the final value. (Same goes for `left` and `right`)

I see two possible ways to achieve what you are trying to accomplish:

1. Use JavaScript to either find the initial or the final value you want to transition from/to.
2. Use CSS' `transform`-property for when transitioning.

Regarding the CSS-only approach:

1. Start at the bottom-right corner
2. Transition to the top-left corner using `bottom: 100%; right: 100%;`. This would place the bottom-right corner of our element on the top-left corner of its parent, essentially placing it outside of the parent by exactly its own width and height.
3. Use the `transform`-property to compensate the overflow that would happen as explained in point 2, since the percentages used in `transform` are relative to the elements dimension, not its parent.

Since `transform` has its initial values defined to be set to 0, it can be transitioned without declaring it beforehand.

See the example below:

```js
// Using 'setTimeout()' does:
// 1. Place the function on the callstack
// 2. Since the script has run, the DOM creation continues
// 3. Page runs for the first time
// 4. Callstack will be worked through
//
// Point 4 means: '.drifted' will be applied after
// the page has initially rendered, making the transition
// a 'must do'-operation for the rendering engine
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('div').classList.add('drifted');
}, 0);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: 2.5s linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div.drifted {
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 100%;
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>I'm drifting!</div>
```